# How can I guess particular solution of a Riccati differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the two following differential equations.

$$y'=6+5y+y^2$$

$$y'=9+6y+y^2$$

I have learned how to solve one with a given particular solution but cannot seem to get my head around this. I need help with guessing the particular solution of both of these.

Comment: you don't have the concept of particular and complementary solutions for nonlinear odes -this is due to the fact you can not simply add solutions together, in general, in a linear fashion. but since you have a separable first order ode I would suggest re-arranging and solve.

Comment: @Chinny84 : It is one technique to transform a Riccati equation in $y$ into a Bernoulli equation in $u$ where $y=y_0+u$ using one particular (in a general sense, not the one restricted to linear ODE) solution $y_0$.

Comment: @lutzl What is $y_0$ A solution to? Is it the solution to transform to the Bernoulli? As I am aware and used that technique often. My original comment was referring (I think) to the fact that we can not add solutions together as we could with linear equations - but I do agree that using a function to transform the equation (as you outlined above) could be defined as a particular solution so you are correct.

Comment: Yes, any one solution to the original ODE. The usual recommendation for text-book exercises is to try $y_0=cx^a$ for constants $a,c$.

Comment: Coming from a Physics background I spent plenty of time working with transforming to Bessel equations. I have also been known to transform the independent variable to try to resolve some of the transforms!

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=6+5y+y^2=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
There is no need for particular solution. Solving is straightforward since it is an autonomous and separable EDO.
$$dx=\frac{dy}{6+5y+y^2}$$
$$x=\int \frac{dy}{6+5y+y^2} = \ln\Big|\frac{y+2}{y+3}\Big|+\text{constant}$$
$$\frac{y+2}{y+3}=c\:e^x$$
$$y(x)=\frac{2-3c\:e^x}{c\:e^x-1}$$
By the way, a particular solution is $y(x)=-2$ which corresponds to the particular case $c=0$. Another particular solution is $y(x)=-3$ which corresponds to the particular case $c=\infty$.

Proceed on the same manner to solve the second ODE, which is even simpler to integrate.

NOTE:

If you really insist to solve the equations as Riccati ODE, you don't necessarily need guessing a particular solution. There is an alternative method without requiring to find a particular solution first. See :
[General Solution to Ricatti Differential Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682008/general-solution-to-ricatti-differential-equations/2682048#2682048)

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a difficult one at first sight  but believe me this is almost the same as one with a given particular solution. You can easily find a particular solution by putting whatever is on the right hand side equal to zero and by a simple factorization you'll get two solutions. Either of them can be your particular solution i.e your "$y_1$". For the above problem $y'=6+5y+y^2$ which by coincidence  I recently did a minute ago for my assignment is as follows

$$6+5y+y^2 = 0 $$

$$ 6+3y+2y+y^2 = 0 $$

$$ (y+3)(y+2) = 0 $$

Either $y=-3$ or $y=-2$, this is your particular solution i.e $y_1=-2$ or $y_1=-3$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can this be modified to work when some or all of the coefficients are non-constant functions of $x$?