# General Solution to Ricatti Differential Equations

Tags: calculus

I’ve been studying general form Ricatti Differential Equations recently, and I’m confused as to why a general form solution is not possible.  What would it mean if a general form solution were possible?

Comment: Please define what you mean with "general form", both for "Ricatti Differential Equation" and for "solution".

Comment: Except for certain rather restricted forms, solutions to differential equations can't be written down in "closed form".  The solution exists, it just doesn't have a finite expression in terms of well-known functions.

Comment: What do you call a general form ? And are you aware that even the simplest ODE $y'=f(x)$ has no closed-form expression in general ?

Comment: By general form Ricatti Differential Equation, I mean a 2nd order polynomial being equal to the derivative of the polynomials unknown variable, and a general form solution being a solution to the polynomial in finite terms of the known coefficients and their derivatives.  Why should it be so that these solutions do not exist?

Answer (score 2):

The well known way to solve the Riccati ODE is first to find a particular solution. Then it is easy to transform it to a first order linear ODE. See Eqs.[7-8} in :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html

But this method fails if one cannot find a particular solution, which unfortunately is generally the case (except in textbook exercises).

Many people think that a first order ODE is always easier to solve than a second order ODE. This is a big mistake, especially in the case of Riccati ODE.

A generally much efficient approach consists in transforming the Riccati ODE, which is a non-linear fist order ODE, into a second order linear ODE. A second order linear ODE is often easier to solve than a first order non-linear ODE.

It is easy to transform the Riccati ODE to a second order linear ODE : See Eqs.[5-6] in the above referenced page.

EXAMPLE :

In this question  [Solve $(x^4+y^4)\,\text{d}x-xy\,\text{d}y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600572/solve-x4y4-textdx-xy-textdy-0/2600788#2600788)
a Riccati equation is involved after some preliminary calculus. One cannot find a particular solution of this Riccati equation (Afterwards it appears that this would require Bessel functions, impossible to guess a-priori). Transforming the Riccati equation into the related second order linear equation leads to a Bessel ODE which solution is known. So, the problem apparently unsolvable on closed form is finally solved in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: interesting really ...+1

Answer (score 1):

If a special solution $y_1$ of the Ricatti Differential Equation is known, then the general solution is obtained as $y=y_1+u$, where $u$ satisfies a Bernoulli equation.

If a special solution of the Ricatti Differential Equation is not known, then, in general, the general form of the solutions is not possible.